# Expand/Fold a Layout when user swipes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

In an Android project, I have an Activity that contains (from top to bottom) a header, a `RecyclerView` and a `RelativeLayout`.

Code sample :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout ...>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the behaviour I want : the `RelativeLayout` is "folded" by default, i.e. under the `RecyclerView`. When the user swipes up, the `RelativeLayout` expands to use the whole screen, and folded again when swipes down.

What is the right way to do it ? As I want the `RelativeLayout` to be BELOW the `RecyclerView` when folded, and OVER it when expanded. I tried setting the dependencies between elements dynamically but couldn't manage to do so.

Thanks for any help or advice on how to organize the activity to get such a behaviour.

**EDIT**

```
This is the XML structure :
<CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </AppBarLayout>

    <RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/top_list"   
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativelayout_footer" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <TextView ...>
        <RecyclerView 
            android:id="@+id/included_list"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the listener :

```
    top_list.setVisibility(playlistOpened ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    app_bar.setVisibility(playlistOpened ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    included_list.setVisibility(playlistOpened ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);

    Transition cb = new ChangeBounds();
    cb.setDuration(1000);
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(slider, cb);

    playlistOpened = ! playlistOpened;
```

As you see, I switch the visibility of the elements in order to reorganise the view. When the `included_list` is set to `VISIBLE`, it pushes up the `TextView`.

The only problem is that the `top_list` and the `app_bar` disappear before being covered by the `RelativeLayout`. I tried adding a `Listener` to the `Transition` and do these when the transition ends, but it doesn't work (I guess because they're not set to `GONE` at the beginning, so the `RelativeLayout` can't move up). Any idea of how to do so ? Maybe I should open another question for it ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Is this about scrolling or about stacking views on top of each other? "BELOW" seems to imply the y-axis, while "OVER" sounds like the z-axis. Do you have more than one item inside your `RecyclerView`? How do plan to reach these elements if the `RelativeLayout` gets in your way everytime you swipe up?

Comment: It's about stacking views. When swiping up with the finger on the RecyclerView, I want it to scroll, normal behaviour. When swiping up with the finger on the RelativeLayout, I want the RelativeLayout to expand to cover the entire screen. And I don't want to reach the elements of the RecyclerView when the RelativeLayout is expanded, only when it's folded. Am I clear ?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't even need to be a swipe up gesture, let's say that swipe up scrolls the RecylerView, and that there is a button in the RelativeLayout to expand/fold it.

Comment: So the `RelativeLayout` is always visible, only sometimes it covers only part (which part exactly? a percentage or what?) of the screen, and sometimes it covers the full screen?

Comment: Yes exactly. When it covers part of the screen, it's a wrap_content, just what it needs to display a line of text and the button to expand/fold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, a final attempt. I am back to `RelativeLayout` and added another one around the `RecyclerView` to fix its scrolling problem. However, transitions get tricky (and the listener complicated) then. In order to prevent the `RecyclerView` from popping away before the `RelativeLayout` with the `TextView` inside fully covers the latter, I had to include a fading transition to the `RecyclerView`, too. Hope this suits you.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlwithrecyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/rlwithtextview"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlwithtextview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:id="@+id/textview"
                android:text="Just a test" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`onClick()`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    RelativeLayout rlWithRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rlwithrecyclerview);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsRlWithRecyclerView;

    RelativeLayout rlWithTextView = findViewById(R.id.rlwithtextview);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsRlWithTextView;

    if (rlWithTextView.getLayoutParams().height == MATCH_PARENT) {
        layoutParamsRlWithTextView = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParamsRlWithRecyclerView = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParamsRlWithRecyclerView.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        layoutParamsRlWithRecyclerView.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.rlwithtextview);
    } else {
        layoutParamsRlWithRecyclerView = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, 0);
        layoutParamsRlWithTextView = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
    }
    layoutParamsRlWithTextView.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    Transition changeBounds = new AutoTransition();
    changeBounds.setDuration(500);
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rlWithRecyclerView, changeBounds);
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rlWithTextView, changeBounds);
    rlWithRecyclerView.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsRlWithRecyclerView);
    rlWithTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsRlWithTextView);
}
```

Although I got credit for the two other answers, I will eventually delete them, since they don't solve the problem.

Comment: Nice job ! Thanks a lot.